# How to align and background colour in css

Tags: html, css, background, alignment

Reference images:

**Required**
[image]
**Current**
[image]

Bottom is my work, top is my goal or as close to as possible.
 I have two questions, why won't my div go to the right side of the page?
 and
 I'm having trouble filling in h1 and div with colour and a boarder any help would 
 be appreciated
 Here is my code that i've been working on, sorry im new to CSS and html still.

```
    body {
            background-image: url("bg.jpg");
         }

    div {   background-color; #cccccc;
            opacity: 0.8;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 3px ridge #cccccc;
            padding: 5px
            margin: 10px
            position:absolute;
            right: 0%;
            top: 0%;
        }

    h1 
        {      background-color; #cccccc;
               padding: 5px;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-size: 40px;
               text-align: center
               opacity: 0.8;
               position:absolute;
               left: 45%;
               top: 60%;
               font-family,sans-serif
               width: 300px;                   
        }    




    </style>
</head>


<body>   
    <header id="header">
    <div class="h1">  
    <h1 style="color:DarkSlateBlue" text-align: center;>Rythm and Blues</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div class="div">
    <h3 style="color:DarkSlateBlue" text-align: center> Artist Name</h3>
    <p style="color:DarkSlateBlue"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suas utinam numquam mea ea, errem neglegentur eum ut. Aliquam
    reformidans et mel. soleat corpora prodesset id quo. ei cibo natum delenit his.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you're missing many semi colons. in your css.

Comment: also you have semi colons where colons should be.

Comment: also missing quotation marks in your inline styles.

Comment: Thank you after you pointed it out that became pretty obvious, about the quotation marks in the inline styles could you show me what you mean?

Comment: would fit in comments, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't fit in comments. Below is some fixes to your syntax.

```
 <style>   
    body {
            background-image: url("bg.jpg");
         }

    .div {   
            background-color: #cccccc;
            opacity: 0.8;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 3px ridge #cccccc;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 10px;
            position:absolute;
            right: 0%;
            top: 0%;
        }

    .h1 
        {      background-color: #cccccc;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-size: 40px;
               text-align: center;
               opacity: 0.8;
               position:absolute;
               left: 45%;
               top: 60%;
               font-family,sans-serif;
               width: 300px;                   
        }    




    </style>
</head>
<body>   
    <div class="h1">  
      <h1 style="color:DarkSlateBlue;text-align: center;">Rythm and Blues</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="div">
      <h3 style="color:DarkSlateBlue" text-align: center> Artist Name</h3>
    <p style="color:DarkSlateBlue"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suas utinam numquam mea ea, errem neglegentur eum ut. Aliquam
    reformidans et mel. soleat corpora prodesset id quo. ei cibo natum delenit his.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful, i've gone really far since you've helped me :). I just need to figure out how to round the edges of the div and how to Fix both there positions so they won't change when i resize the browser

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp should point you in the right direction for rounded corners.

Comment: using pixel or em position from the left instead of percentages and right positioning should keep the elements 'fixed'.